# Sun Grid Engine (SGE) Jobs Not Visible After Adding virtual_free

Tags: gridengine

I'm trying to to use virtual_free to limit the number of large memory jobs running each grid node in my cluster. This seems to be working as expected.

After I modified my code to submit jobs with the memory instances, qstat -f -q $queueName no longer shows a list of jobs waiting for a slot.

The jobs are submitted with a specific queue (-q $queueName).

I'm guessing this is happening due to the magic of SGE queue selection. Is there a way to make my jobs show up as before?

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

I'm using:

qstat -f -u * -q $queueName

to view the queue. If I drop the queue argument, I can see the jobs. If I examine a specific job, I can see that it has the correct hard_queue_list value set.

I'm also using Sun Grid Engine 6.1u4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jobs are *requesting* a queue. They're not actually *in* the queue until they have started running on a host which has an instance of that queue. You'll only see them in the queue-specific output if and when they actually start running in the requested queue. This makes perfect sense if you consider the fact that you can use wildcards in your queue requests.

Comment: Is there a way to make the jobs show up when I run qstat -f -u \* -q someQueue.q? Like a slight modification to the command?

Comment: There's not an easy way to do that. Personally I've made a bunch of custom commands that parse the `qstat -j -xml` output and display what exactly I'm looking for as the standard `qstat` output doesn't cover all possible use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If they do not show up in `qstat` then they are not submitted or are crashed already, the SGE magic for queue selection kicks in after they are submitted. Also check that qstat is reporting on the user which submitted that job!

If you have jobs with unmet constraints then SGE will simply queue until they are available.

Comment: That's definitely not the case. qstat -f -u \* -q bas.q. The jobs are definitely there, I just can't see them until they are running. If I don't specify a queue, I can see them, but they aren't attached to a queue.